# ReactJS taking data from API

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

- Hello guys i don't know how to take data from API.
- To be more specific, i have a API like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "free_courses": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Kiến Thức Nhập Môn IT",
        "slug": "lessons-for-newbie",
        "description": "Để có cái nhìn tổng quan về ngành IT - Lập trình web các bạn nên xem các videos tại khóa này trước nhé.",
        "image": "courses/7.png",
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

- In reactjs, i have something like this:

  function Contact() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState({});

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const url = "https://api-gateway.fullstack.edu.vn/api/combined-courses";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const responseJSON = await response.json();
        setProducts(responseJSON);
        //console.log("ResponseJSON:", responseJSON);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Failed to fetch products: ", error);
      }
    };
    getProducts();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {
        <div className="contact-container">
          {products.map((product) => (
            <ul key={product._id}>
              <h1>{product.title}</h1>
              <h2>{product.description}</h2>
            </ul>
          ))}
        </div>
      }
    </>
  );
  ```

  }
- When I refresh the page and I got an error like this:
  Uncaught TypeError: products.map is not a function
- I can get the //console.log("ResponseJSON:", responseJSON); and see my data from console.log but when I render it on the website and it announced an error. Thus, anyone can help me to fix my problem.
- Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: Do this `useState([])` instead of this `useState({})`. You cant't map on a object like that. `products` should be an array from the beginning not an object you are changing it vice versa at the moment. The error is showing because you are working on an object which has no function `map()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make your state as an array :

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
```

Also , your response from the fetch should be an array ...
or , you have to save it in the form of array , so that **map** function works properly.

Just add a check before you render elements of a list .

```
<div className="contact-container">
        {products?.length&&products.map((product) => (
          <ul key={product._id}>
            <h1>{product.title}</h1>
            <h2>{product.description}</h2>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
```

This must solve your issue .

Answer (score -1):

you should add a question mark after products, it checks if pruducts has array then map through them
{products?.map((product) =>